# Delete all but X newest entries in two joined MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, left-join

I'm experimenting with a query that I'll use for pruning two related mysql tables.  I'll be using it to delete all but the most recent entries.

This query behaves exactly as I expect:

```
SELECT
    O.id  AS O_id,
    T.id  AS T_id
FROM
    rt.ObjectCustomFieldValues    AS O
    LEFT JOIN rt.Transactions     AS T
        ON O.id = T.NewReference
WHERE
        O.Disabled    = 1
    AND O.CustomField = 58
    AND O.ObjectId    = 202784
    AND T.id NOT IN (
                        SELECT
                            id
                        FROM
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    id
                                FROM
                                    Transactions
                                WHERE
                                    Field = 58
                                    AND ObjectId = 202784
                                ORDER BY
                                    Created DESC
                                LIMIT 5
                            ) Test
                    )
```

For the rows containing ObjectId 202784, I get the ObjectCustomFieldValues ids and the Transactions ids for all but the most recent 5 items.

Now how do I turn this into a general query that I can run over all rows instead of specifying the ObjectId manually?

To summarize, for field id 58, I want to iterate all ObjectId values and for each one, delete all but the most recent ObjectCustomFieldValues and Transactions.

You can view schema details here:
https://github.com/bestpractical/rt/blob/stable/etc/schema.mysql#L112

and here:

https://github.com/bestpractical/rt/blob/stable/etc/schema.mysql#L328

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is not `INSERT`ing data with a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, depending on your entire database structure order, this could be difficult. If you add a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` you can use `ORDER BY` correctly no matter what.

Comment: `Created` is a DATETIME column, so `ORDER BY Created DESC` is working perfectly.  Like I said, the above query works perfectly, I'm just having trouble figuring out how to run it over all rows, not just rows specific associated with a specific ObjectId.